# Make Border Scale Up on Load WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-animation, wpf-style

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the simple setup below is not working.  I just want a border to scale up ("zoom in") once its loaded, with the zoom-in functionality wrapped up in a resource style.  But when the following XAML runs, the border just loads at 100% scale, no animation happens.  Your help will be much appreciated!

```
    <Style x:Key="SZoomIn" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>            
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SBorder" BasedOn="{StaticResource SZoomIn}" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- ....... -->

    <Border Style="{StaticResource SBorder}"/>
```

**EDIT**:  I did not show the complete markup above so that things could be kept simple, but my *complete* markup is below.  Note that, because there are buttons inside the Border, the Border *does* have Height/Width at run-time.

```
<Window x:Name="StartWindow" x:Class="MEACruncher.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MEACruncher"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MEA Cruncher" Height="393" Width="659" Margin="0" WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/NeuronBackground.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Window.Background>
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BabyBlue">#FF4D7EB8</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBkgrd">#B2000000</SolidColorBrush>
    <Style x:Key="SBtn" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BabyBlue}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="STopBtn" BasedOn="{StaticResource SBtn}" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SBottomBtn" BasedOn="{StaticResource SBtn}" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SZoomIn" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ScaleTransform/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0"/>
                            <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>            
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SBorder" BasedOn="{StaticResource SZoomIn}" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BabyBlue}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlackBkgrd}"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SStackPnl" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>            
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Border x:Name="MainBorder" Style="{StaticResource SBorder}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPnl" Style="{StaticResource SStackPnl}">
        <Button x:Name="ViewProjectsBtn" Content="View Projects" Style="{StaticResource STopBtn}" Click="ViewProjectsBtn_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="AboutBtn" Content="About" Style="{StaticResource SBtn}" Click="AboutBtn_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="ExitBtn" Content="Exit" Style="{StaticResource SBottomBtn}" Click="ExitBtn_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>

</Window>
```

Comment: Works for me. If I add an explicit size. `<Border Style="{StaticResource SBorder}" Background="Blue" Width="150" Height="110" />`

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi I left out some markup for this example.  My actual border contains some other controls that give it a width and height.  But that width and height is not being animated on load :(

Answer (score 1):

If above is all your `XAML` then change your code as following:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource SBorder}" Background="Red" Height="200" Width="200"/>
```

> ***You have set `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`a and not set aby `Height` & `Width` in Border so it will not display
>   at all. Either give Height & Width some value or set
>   `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` and you'll
>   see the `Animation` will work fine. as below:***

```
 <Style x:Key="SBorder" BasedOn="{StaticResource SZoomIn}" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    </Style>
```

If you have some other control hierarchy then update that in question and I'll update my answer for that.

**Update:**

In your updated markup Border will have `Height` & `Width` at render time. But the `SZoomIn` style seems different from the XAML given before. You are not setting the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` property correctly. You are missing `RenderTransform` prefix in it.

***so the solution is:***

> ***Replace your `Storyboard` in latest `XAML` from `Storyboard` in first `XAML`.***

Comment: (awesome name btw).  I have edited the original post to show my complete markup, which does give the Border a run-time Height/Width.

Comment: @Rabadash8820 thanks pal. and see my updated answer. :)

Comment: Sorry, I was actually experimenting with that and forgot to change it back, I have edited my original post.  The zoom-in does not work whether I include "RenderTransform" or not

Comment: @Rabadash8820 are you sure? I just used your code and animation works fine.

Comment: Wow, you know what you're right.  I just figured out the issue and I'll post that as the answer.  +1 for your well-formatted and helpful answers though!

Answer (score 0):

So, as mentioned in the comments, the code that I posted here actually does work fine.  The issue was with *one* other markup element that I left out of the original post.  I created a class called DraggableArea that inherits from ContentControl, and this element surrounded my Border (see FULL markup below).  DraggableArea makes any content draggable with the mouse.  I left it out b/c I figured everyone would focus on that and not look at the surrounding XAML, where I was sure the problem lay.  Turns out I was wrong, and as usual my custom code was causing the bug.  Not sure exactly why the bug is happening yet but there you go.  Thanks for all the help though!

```
<local:DraggableArea>
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" Style="{StaticResource SBorder}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPnl" Style="{StaticResource SStackPnl}">
            <Button x:Name="ViewProjectsBtn" Content="View Projects" Style="{StaticResource STopBtn}" Click="ViewProjectsBtn_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="AboutBtn" Content="About" Style="{StaticResource SBtn}" Click="AboutBtn_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="ExitBtn" Content="Exit" Style="{StaticResource SBottomBtn}" Click="ExitBtn_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</local:DraggableArea>
```

Comment: if you want to use local:DraggableArea. can you give it's code. I can look into the actual problem.

Comment: @KyloRen Thanks, I really appreciate your help!  Everything is actually working as I wanted it now, though I don't quite know HOW its working.  Such is programming, haha.  I'd be happy to get your input on my DraggableArea code but its >100 lines long and would seem inappropriate to post on this thread.

Comment: OK. understood. It was just every time I work on a different problem like yours I learn new things about WPF behavior. but since you made your code work fine. there is no point investigating further. and thanks for replaying. :)